Error: Static method 'buildExpression' requires that 'HStack<TupleView<(Text, Text)>>' conform to 'AccessibilityRotorContent'
I have a view with a ForEach. Within the ForEach, I get an error on my HStacks saying they need to conform to AccessibilityRotorContent. HStacks outside of the ForEach don't produce the error. What other code is relevant here?
Any ideas why this could be happening?
I have tried rebuilding the file from scratch with no change.
Here's my code:
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct DayView: View {
    var residentController = ResidentController.shared
    var date: Date
    var appointments: [Appointment] = []
    var body: some View {
        Text(date.formatted(date: .complete, time: .omitted))
        
        Divider().padding(.vertical)
        
        ForEach(appointments, id: \.self) { appointment in
            
                HStack() {
                    Text("Resident Name:")
                    Text(appointment.firstName + " " + appointment.lastName)
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Resident Phone Number:")
                    Text(appointment.phoneNumber)
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Appointment Date:")
                    Text(appointment.date.dayOfWeek() + " " + appointment.date.returnDateWithOneMoreDay.formatted(date: .long, time: .omitted))
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Appointment Time:")
                    Text(appointment.time)
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Resident House: ")
                    Text(appointment.house)
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Resident Address: ")
                    Text(appointment.residentAddress)
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Description: ")
                    Text(appointment.description)
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Appointment Address: ")
                    Text(appointment.addressOfAppt)
                }
                
                Divider().padding(.vertical)
            }
        }
    
    func timeString(from iso8601String: String) -> String? {
        let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.formatOptions = [.withTime, .withDashSeparatorInDate, .withColonSeparatorInTime]
        
        if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: iso8601String) {
            let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
            timeFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
            return timeFormatter.string(from: date)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}


and here are my extensions:
func dayOfWeek() -> String {
                let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
                return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
            }

func returnDateWithOneMoreDay(date: Date) -> Date {
            var calendar = Calendar.current
            var datePlusOne = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date)!
            
            return datePlusOne
        }


You seems to do some strange additions in your Text : not sure dayOfWeek is a string. To find out where the problem is : comment your HStack in the ForEach and add them one by one to find the falty one. The compiler gives sometimes error on ForEach when something is wrong in the code inside it.

I see you have edited the question now so I have to ask why don't you do as suggested and comment out parts to identify the incorrect code? We don't know your data source and its definition so we can't do it and it should be pretty straight forward thing to do.

I followed the suggestion and through the process of elimination found that this line was causing the trouble:
HStack {
                    Text("Appointment Date:")
                    Text(appointment.date.dayOfWeek() + " " + appointment.date.returnDateWithOneMoreDay.formatted(date: .long, time: .omitted))
                }

Here's the refactored solution:
ForEach(appointments, id: \.self) { appointment in
            
            var dateString = appointment.date.formatted(date: .complete, time: .omitted)
            
                HStack() {
                    Text("Resident Name:")
                    Text(appointment.firstName + " " + appointment.lastName)
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Resident Phone Number:")
                    Text(appointment.phoneNumber)
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Appointment Date:")
                    Text(dateString)
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Appointment Time:")
                    Text(appointment.time)
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Resident House: ")
                    Text(appointment.house)
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Resident Address: ")
                    Text(appointment.residentAddress)
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Description: ")
                    Text(appointment.description)
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Appointment Address: ")
                    Text(appointment.addressOfAppt)
                }
                
                Divider().padding(.vertical)
            }


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
